# Is there more efficient (time complexity) method instead of StandardOutput.ReadToEnd?

Tags: c#, performance, time-complexity

I want to make more fast my projects. I used Stopwatch class and calculated time between this code blocks. Most of time is spending in `string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` line. Is there any suggestion to use instead of this codes?

```
Process p = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
startInfo.FileName = DBUpdater_Adresi;         
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo = startInfo;
p.Start();
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
p.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason that most of the time is spent on that line, is that it waits for the entire execution of the program that you started. It doesn't take time because it's inefficient, it takes time because it's waiting for the other process.

The last line waits for the process to exit, but the time from the output stream being closed to the time the process ends it very little.